use 'param' instead of 'args' in yaml launch-file?
I'm writing a launch file to start tf2_ros nodes. I'm using elements like :
  - node:
      pkg: "tf2_ros"
      exec: "static_transform_publisher"
      args: '--frame-id $(var world_id) --child-frame-id L1'

-> this file works fine.
My other yaml files use 'param:' list, with key-value dict. I tried to re-write my 'args' with this 'param' key, but args are not recognized.
Is it impossible or did I do wrong ?
Here is one of my try:
  - node:
      pkg: "tf2_ros"
      exec: "static_transform_publisher"
      param:
        -
          name: "frame-id"
          value: $(var world_id)
        -
          name: "child-frame-id"
          value: "L1"

-> error parsing command line arguments: Frame id must not be empty

tf2_ros does not work with parameters as the arguments are not declared as parameters in the node. Please have a look at this file for detailed information. When you launch static_transform_publisher, you basically call this file.
If you go to line#330 (help section), you will notice that data is passed as arguments, not as parameters.
